# Headphones detected but not working in Kubuntu 20.04 (Rog-Strix-GL503GE laptop)

Tags: sound, 20.04, kubuntu, asus, headphones

I tried:

- alsamixer
- alsactl restore
- alsa force-reload
- pavucontrol
- sudo modprobe snd-hda-codec-idt 
  but nothing seems to work. when i write $ lspci | grep Audio, the output is (00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)).

Comment: Are your headphones displayed in the list of output-devices?

Comment: Yes they are, and I can also see blue line moving if I speak in my mic, but there is no sound.